# SQL join where value in second table is first lower value w.r.t the first table

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have 2 tables and both of them have a column that contains `timestamp` for various events. The timestamp values in both the tables are different as they are for different events.
I want to join the two tables such that every record in table1 is joined with first lower timestamp on table2.

```
For e.g. 
Table1       Table2
142.13       141.16 
157.34       145.45
168.45       155.85
170.23       166.76
             168.44

Joined Table should be:
142.13,141.16
157.34,155.85
168.45,166.76
170.23,168.44
```

I am using Apache Spark SQL.

I am a noob in SQL and this doesn't look like job for a noob :). Thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What if you have more records in one of the tables? should they be left out?

Comment: I am using Spark SQL. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are more records and I want to ignore those. I just need the first lower record. If it helps to provide context, these are log messages and I am correlating log messages across 2 different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditto has shown the straight-forward way to solve this. If Apache Spark really has problems with this very basic query, then join first (which can lead to a big intermediate result) and aggregate then:

```
select t1.v, max(t2.v)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.v <= t1.v
group by t1.v
order by t1.v;
```

Comment: Yayy !! This seems to be working. Tried with some dummy data. Will try with real data tomorrow. Thanks a lot. You guys are awesome. Never received such quick responses. Have a good day. :)

Comment: please see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944087/sql-join-with-selecting-previous-matching-value-with-group-by/44945322?noredirect=1#comment76867110_44945322). This query is not working for this dataset. Can you please suggest suitable modification? Thanks. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c270/3/0

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  with t1 as (
           select 142.13 v from dual union all
           select 157.34 v from dual union all
           select 168.45 v from dual union all
           select 170.23 v from dual 
        ),
        t2 as (
        select 141.16 v from dual union all 
        select 145.45 v from dual union all
        select 155.85 v from dual union all
        select 166.76 v from dual union all
        select 168.44 v from dual 
        )
  select v, ( select max(v) from t2 where t2.v <= t1.v )
    from t1;


           V (SELECTMAX(V)FROMT2WHERET2.V<=T1.V)
  ---------- -----------------------------------
      142.13                              141.16
      157.34                              155.85
      168.45                              168.44
      170.23                              168.44

  4 rows selected.
```

the WITH clause is just me faking the data ... 
the simplified query is just:

```
  select t1.v, ( select max(t2.v) from table2 t2 where t2.v <= t1.v ) from table1 t1
```

[edit]
admittedly, I'm not familiar with Spark  .. but this is simple enough SQL .. I'm assuming it works :) 
[/edit]

Comment: I tried to convert this to Spark SQL but it is failing and failing with a scary error. What does the last '/' do here? This is my Spark SQL query.  `SELECT frame_number, (select max(frame_number) from t2 where t2.frame_number <= t1.frame_number) from t1`. Scary error is `Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate`

Comment: Looking at the error, looks like Spark SQL doesn't support correlated queries where the two value are not equal. Have I read that correctly?

Comment: @Nikhil: Ok .. so ignore the final "/" .. that's just small syntax difference on platform. But aside from that, doing a quick search, it seems that Spark should support basic ANSI sql .. which means that query as I've got it should work.  You do have to change your table names and col names ... since you didn't provide them in your example.  If you give more detail, I'll update my answer to match your details better.

Comment: Looks to be lack of support in Spark SQL. When I removed "<" the query worked. `spark.sql("SELECT crcdftable.frame_number, (select max(dfxtable.frame_number) from dfxtable where dfxtable.frame_number = crcdftable.frame_number) from crcdftable")`

Comment: @NikhilUtane: the `/` is an Oracle (actually SQL\*Plus) specific thing. Just use the standard `;` to terminate the statement instead (in this case the `/` wouldn't be needed in Oracle either)

Comment: @Nikhil: wow ... that's .. surprising .. O.o  ok, then go with what Thorsten posted then .. try his :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thx .. I did edit the answer and removed the slash from the simplified simpler query. From the examples I saw via google, it didn't seem like even the semi-colon was needed?  *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache spark sql then you can join these two tables as dataframes with a adding a column using `monotonically_increasing_id()`

```
val t1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(142.13, 157.34, 168.45, 170.23)).toDF("c1")
val t2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(141.16,145.45,155.85,166.76,168.44)).toDF("c2")

val t11 = t1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
val t22 = t2.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

val res = t11.join(t22, t11("id") + 1 === t22("id") ).drop("id")
```

Output:

```
+------+------+
|    c1|    c2|
+------+------+
|142.13|145.45|
|168.45|166.76|
|157.34|155.85|
|170.23|168.44|
+------+------+
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The first output for c2 is incorrect. Here it should be 141.16. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this you are asking ". I want to join the two tables such that every record in table1 is joined with first lower timestamp on table2."

Comment: Yes, so 142.13 should be joined with 141.16 which is just lower than 142.13.