# SQL join with selecting previous matching value with group by

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 tables that I want to join on a key that matches with the **first previous** record.

I have a query that does this. However I also want to include a column in the results from each of the table. This forces me to include those 2 columns in the Group By attribute which is returning duplicate results.

The query I am using is similar to this (courtesy: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546168/sql-join-where-value-in-second-table-is-first-lower-value-w-r-t-the-first-table/44548356?noredirect=1#comment76087603_44548356)):

```
SELECT t1.frame as frame1,
    t1.string as string1,
    max(t2.frame) as frame2,
    t2.string as string2
    FROM t1 
    JOIN t2 
    ON t2.frame < t1.frame and 
    t1.key=t2.key
    GROUP BY t1.frame, t2.frame, t1.string, t2.string
    ORDER BY t2.frame
```

The (problem) output I see is:

```
frame1, string1, frame2, string2 
51      text1     6       text2   
107253  text3     6       text2
```

How can I include string2 in my results such that I don't want to group by it but only include its value for corresponding frame2?

I tried setting this up on sqlfiddle.com to make it easy to try. I populated with some dummy data but here along with this problem, I also see another problem which is it is also returning results where frame2=2. This is not expected, since it should always match frame=6. I suppose this may be side effect of grouping by string2?

[Link to sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e0e94/12/0)

Here I expect the output should only be 1 record which is:

```
frame1,string1,frame2,string2
51      text1    6     text2
```

I am doing this on Spark SQL but this should be a generic SQL question.
Thanks.

Edit: 
My data consists of incoming packets and I want to match a packet to the most recent one that came before it which has the matching ID. For e.g.

```
Table t2:
    frame#1:Key=a,Text=abc
    frame#2:Key=a,Text=def
    frame#3:Key=b,Text=efg
    frame#5:Key=c,Text=xyz

Table t1:
    frame#4:Key=a,Text=pqr
    frame#6:Key=c,Text=mno
```

So here, for frame#4 from t1, I want to match it with frame from t2 that has come before it and has the same key. So it should match with frame#2 (not frame#3 coz key is different and not frame#1 coz frame#2 is more recent). Similarly, frame#6 should match with frame#5.

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Can you more accurately define what a "first previous record" is please?

Comment: Sorry. Added more details.

Comment: So does your production system have 2 tabkles? Your example data stream is only single table you see.. That's fine, we can cope with it.. it's just instead of having "t1 and t2" we have "t1 where type=1" and "t1 where type=2" -> using a where clause in 2 subqueries to conceptually create 2 tables

Comment: @NikhilUtane  : can you see if my update (see the end of the answer, after NEW AFTER YOUR NEW POSTED SAMPLE DATA) is what you had in mind?

Comment: @etsa - see the "not frame#1 coz frame#2 is more recent" requirement - I think your MIN will always select the text from frame#1..

Comment: @NikhilUtane: are you speaking about my last (3rd) query?  The one after  the words NEW AFTER YOUR NEW POSTED SAMPLE DATA in bold?  There I don't use MIN...

Comment: @CaiusJard. Yes it is 2 tables. By example I meant at the beginning of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*, t1.string AS string1, t2.string AS string2
FROM
(SELECT t1.frame AS frame1, MAX(t2.frame) AS frame2
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.key=t2.key AND t2.frame< t1.frame
GROUP BY t1.frame
) A
INNER JOIN t1 ON A.frame1=t1.frame
INNER JOIN t2 ON A.frame2=t2.frame;
```

Output:

```
    frame1  frame2  string1 string2
1   51      6       text13  text17
2   107253  106999  text25  text39
```

Comment: This method won't work for the posted example, because it will take the text from frame#1 rather than frame#2. It works coincidentally for the posted sqlfiddle because there are only 2 keys of value '100' in the example table. If a third appears, it'll start retrieving the wrong value.. At least that's how I understand the definition of "first previous" now == "the one before the most recent one", rather than "the very first that ocurred in the past"

Comment: @etsa, actually there is no type field. Based on the type field the data is already separated into the two tables, t1 and t2. I will try and modify your query to use 2 tables. If you could provide with the modified query, then that would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: No, its not working as it is supposed to. It is giving  2 records with 107253 as frame1. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7581a/5/0

Comment: Pls use my sample data, and explain me expected result.

Comment: @etsa, please see the output being displayed here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c270/4/0. I want same output to come but with additional string columns for both the table. Hope this is clear. Thanks.

Comment: @NikhilUtane  see new version

Comment: BTW the key is not a simple comparison. It involves a CASE-THEN-ELSE. I will try this myself. If any problem then will come back. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

THis query strips the tables down to "just the latest row" where "latest" is defined as "having the highest int value for the key column".

That's what the row_number() over() function does; assigns an incrementing number to a row, restarts it whenever key changes, and rows with the same key are ordered by frame descending, so the latest is always rownumber 1

```
SELECT 
    a.frame as frame1,
    a.string as string1,
    b.frame as frame2  
FROM 
  (SELECT 
   frame, 
   key, 
   string, 
   row_number() over(partition by key order by frame desc) as rown
   from t1
  ) a 
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT 
   frame, 
   key, 
   string, 
   row_number() over(partition by key order by frame desc) as rown
   from t2
  ) b
  ON a.rown = 1 and a.key = b.key and b.rown=1
```

if you need to change the definition of "latest" then change the **order by** to be ascending (it will give the lowest number of frame)

If as per my comment your definition of "first previous" differs, i.e. you want the row before the latest, (where a higher key number is "later") then make it rown = 2 in the ON clause, and make the **order by** to be key descending

(Perhaps it will help you if you just run the subqueries on their own, then look at the data and say "the rows I want always have a **rown** of X")

Update:

I suspect from your recent update that you want the ON clause to be where rown=2 for probably one of your tables if not the other. Because it's not clear to me which one of your tables is "behind" you'll have to edit the answer above a bit in sqlfiddle.. Here's a version that produces your requested output

```
SELECT 
    a.frame as frame1,
    a.string as string1,
    b.frame as frame2,
    b.string 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
   frame, 
   key, 
   string, 
   row_number() over(partition by key order by frame desc) as rown
   from t1
  ) a 
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT 
   frame, 
   key, 
   string, 
   row_number() over(partition by key order by frame desc) as rown
   from t2
  ) b
  ON a.rown = 2 and a.key = b.key and b.rown=1
```

You might want to test this on larger data sets

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work on different data set. Here it should return 2 records, but it is only returning 1. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c270/1/0

Comment: What 2 results are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/47c11/2

```
select distinct on (t.frame1, t.key1, t.string1)
    t.* 
from
    (select 
        t1.frame frame1, t1.key key1, t1.string string1, t2.frame frame2, t2.key key2, t2.string string2
    from 
         t1 
    join 
         t2 
    on 
         t1.key=t2.key
         and t1.frame > t2.frame
    order by 
         t2.frame desc) t
```

Comment: No. actually, the t1.string and t2.string are a comma separated list of values which may not be in same order. That's why I am joining the table and then processing those 2 strings to verify if they are matching or not.

Comment: How about to [sort the string column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769913/sql-server-sort-comma-separated-string-in-one-column) first?

Comment: This is on Apache Spark. So not traditional RDBMS that I can update. It's look straight-forward to just join the 2 tables on the key and then process the 2 columns and verify they are same.

Comment: I don't know Apache Spark; but I've updated the answer based on your modified question. The key is to use "order by" and "top 1". Hope it can give you some inspiration. Good luck.

Comment: Top 1 will not help here. I want all matching records (where key is same and is most recent) and not just 1 result. Thanks

Comment: Let us try with postgresql. PLease check the updated answer.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Try the updated answer, which should work now.

Comment: No it didn't work as desired. Here frame#51 should join with frame#6. But it is joining with frame#106999. I

Comment: Ok. Can you post the frame#106999? Let me test it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148513/discussion-between-dy-w-and-nikhil-utane).

Comment: Thanks DY. Your latest solution is also working as intended.